# Is it possible to use MQ with Katalon?

Tags: ibm-mq, katalon-studio

I'm trying to find informations which explain how use IBM MQ with Katalon.

However, I didn't found any informations about that...

Do you know if it is possible? With a plugin? A custom Java/Groovy code?

I hope that someone could give an answer to this question.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by using MQ with Kataon ?
Having test steps that produces / consumes to / from a MQ ?

Comment: Exactly. I try to know if it is possible to put message in a queue with Katalon. Like JMeter can do it for example.

Answer (score 2):

You can add external librairies to your Katalon Studio ([source](https://docs.katalon.com/katalon-studio/docs/external-libraries.html)), so you can easily write a producer / consumer in Java and then use them your test steps.

You can use *WebSphere MQ JMS Extensions* that provides basic implementations.

[Here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/package-summary.html) is the javadoc of the package that contains everything you need, especially [MQMessageProducer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQMessageProducer.html) and [MQMessageConsumer](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQMessageConsumer.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if it exists some librairies to do that? To not do something which already exists...

Comment: @N.Lamblin you'll find links to the javadoc of their JMS implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about sending messages from Katalon to chat/messaging apps then yes.

For example, you can send JSON HTTP Post requests to Slack and Rocket chat. And I guess most of the newest chat apps can do something similar.

For details about Slack message format, see [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Comment: My bad, I forgot to mentionned that but the MQ to use is an IBM MQ. I updated my post.

Comment: No problem, it should still be possible to consume API requests: https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/learn-mq/mq-tutorials/ibm-mq-messaging-rest-api/. The principles are the same, but someone who used IBM MQ should know more.